# How to use Angular's ng-model with jQuery UI's slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI's slider on one of my pages and I would like to use ng-model to bind the value to my controller.  The slider renders like below:

```
<div id="speakerSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-slider-pips" aria-disabled="false">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 40%;"></a>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-first ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-0 ui-slider-pip-selected-initial" style="left: 0%">
     <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="0">0</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-1" style="left: 20.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="1">1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-2 ui-slider-pip-selected" style="left: 40.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="2">2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-3" style="left: 60.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="3">3</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-4" style="left: 80.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="4">4</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-last ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-5" style="left: 100%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span>
      <span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="5">5</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

According to [angulars documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) `ng-model` can only be used on `input`, `select` or `textArea` elements.  Since none of these are part of the slider can I not use ng-model?  My other thought was to create a hidden input and insert the value in there every time the slider updates.  Is this my best option, or is there a better work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ngModel with a custom control: create a custom directive, get a [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelControlle) reference, and use the necessary methods/properties (`$render`,`$setViewValue`,`$viewValue`) to update the slider/model.

Modified from [angularjs example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive('slider', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // Initialize slider and setup change event to enable updating the value
      jQuery(element).slider({
        'change': function() {
            scope.$evalAsync(setModelValue);
        }
      });
      
      //Read data from model into custom control
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        jQuery(element).slider("value",ngModel.$viewValue || 0);
      };

      setModelValue();

      // Write data from control to the model
      function setModelValue() {
        var value = jQuery(element).slider("value");
        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/master/dist/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/master/dist/jquery-ui-slider-pips.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  {{slideval}}
  
<div id="speakerSlider" slider ng-model="slideval" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-slider-pips" aria-disabled="false">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 40%;"></a>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-first ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-0 ui-slider-pip-selected-initial" style="left: 0%">
     <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="0">0</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-1" style="left: 20.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="1">1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-2 ui-slider-pip-selected" style="left: 40.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="2">2</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-3" style="left: 60.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="3">3</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-4" style="left: 80.0000%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="4">4</span>
    </span>
    <span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-last ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-5" style="left: 100%">
      <span class="ui-slider-line"></span>
      <span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="5">5</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Note the demo doesn't fully use the pips you will have to hook that functionality up yourself.

---

Using the hidden input method would almost be the same, you would still need a couple events to keep track of everything and update the slider/model.

Hidden input code example

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="speakerSlider">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="slideval">
        <-- rest of slider code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller("myCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.slideval = 0;        

    var slider = jQuery("#speakerSlider");        
    slider.slider({
        change:function(){
            $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
               $scope.slideval = slider.slider("value");
            });
        }
    });

    //This is required so if you do
    //$scope.slideval = 5
    //the slider will be updated
    //otherwise you would have to do slider("value",...) every time
    $scope.$watch('slideval', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       slider.slider("value",newValue);
    });
}]);
```

While you do not have the overhead of the directive code, there are a couple cons to this:

1. You create a second watcher. One watcher is already created for the ng-model for the hidden input. Since you do not have access to it, you have to setup the `$scope.$watch` in the controller to watch for any changes so you can act on it. If it is possible to get access to the original watcher I am not aware of the process to do so.
2. Not as modular, you would have to copy/change the code for each individual slider(or setup a constructor where you can pass in $scope, but would still need to call that in every controller), whereas with a directive path all you would have to do is add `slider ng-model="model"` to each slider

Comment: It seems like the hidden input solution would be simpler, possibly only two lines: one to create the hidden input with the ng-model attribute and one in the sliders slide event to set the hidden element's value.  If it is this simple, is there a reason that your solution would be better?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, Using a directive is more modular, and would use one less watcher. It is not a huge difference, but I like the modular approach as it keeps the code separate. Updated answer to show.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-model` isn't just for native form elements - the documentation also mentions "custom form control" in the first paragraph.

Here is a library that provides a jQueryUI slider directive for angular:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider

Demo page: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html

I recommend the talk [Using ngModelController to Make Sexy Custom Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVzymluqmg4) from ng-conf 2014 to explain how ngModelController works for custom form elements.

Comment: It seems like the hidden input solution would be simpler, possibly only two lines: one to create the hidden input with the ng-model attribute and one in the sliders slide event to set the hidden element's value. If it is this simple, is there a reason that your solution would be better?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create variables on your scope and bind those to each slider.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('sliderCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.slider1 = 1;
});

<span class="ui-slider-pip ui-slider-pip-last ui-slider-pip-label ui-slider-pip-1" style="left: 100%">
  <span class="ui-slider-line"></span>
  <span class="ui-slider-label" data-value="{{slider1}}">1</span>
</span>
```

Theres also a few other slider modules that are angular friendly:

https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider

https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider

Comment: I should point out that each of the slider points has `data-value` defined.  It's whether the slider point has the class `ui-slider-pip-selected` that determines where on the slider we are.  So in my example the slider knob is on `data-value="2"` because it's parent has the `ui-slider-pip-selected` class